# Usage example for super(type, type2)

Tags: python

Can someone suggest a usage scenario for:

```
super(type,type2)
```

I can only think of one case where I want to call a similarly named classmethod method in superclass of `type` when there exists a method of the same name in `type2` also.

Answer (score 2):

It's mostly for `__new__`:

```
class MyStr(str):
    def __new__(cls, val):
        return super(MyStr, cls).__new__(cls, val.upper())
```